# Exporting selected attributes in ArcGIS to a new layer using python (ArcMap 10.5.1)?

Tags: python, arcgis

I have a file with data from 25 different years and I need to export the data in each individual year into a new shapefile.  I have already coded a way to select the files but now I need help exporting the data from the year that I selected into a new shapefile.  The selection of the year involves the SelectLayerByAttribute_management function if that helps gives you an idea of how I coded for the selection.  For practical purposes just say that the main file that I am pulling the data out of is called "Customers" and I would like to export the individual years into new shapefiles called "Customers_20xx".

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Customers", "NEW_SELECTION", "Year=1989")
<Result 'Customers'>
```

That part works. When I enter that code every data set that was from the year 1989 in the file "Customers" is selected. Now it is just a matter of exporting the selected data into a new files called "Customers_1989" – PythonPerson 2 hours ago

Comment: It'll be much easier to help if you share the code that you already made.

Comment: >>> import arcpy
>>>arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Customers","NEW_SELECTION","Year=1989")
<Result 'Customers'>
>>>

Comment: The <Result 'Customers'> >>> was automated when I pressed enter.  The only part that I did is everything before that.

Comment: That part works.  When I enter that code every data set that was from the year 1989 in the file "Customers" is selected.  Now it is just a matter of exporting the selected data into a new files called "Customers_1989"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/data/mexico.gdb"

# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("cities", "lyr") 

# Select all cities which overlap the chihuahua polygon
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr", "intersect", "chihuahua", 0, "new_selection")

# Within selected features, further select only those cities which have a population > 10,000   
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", '"population" > 10000')

# Write the selected features to a new featureclass
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", "chihuahua_10000plus")
```

The last line perhaps is the one you're looking for. If you run that on a layer which has a selection, only the selected features will be exported. However, if you do that on a feature class or a shapefile, all features will be copied.

If you haven't made a layer file from the feature class or shapefile, then I suggest you do that using `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("cities", "lyr")` command.